# Why does oracle.com nameservers' produce inconsistent results?

Tags: networking, debian, dns, internet, cloudflare

When I dig Oracle's text files it fails after about two seconds.

```
$ dig oracle.com txt

; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4-5.1+deb10u2-Debian <<>> oracle.com txt
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 41554
;; flags: qr; QUERY: 0, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; Query time: 2008 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.86.1#53(192.168.86.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Jul 14 11:17:28 CDT 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 12
```

However I'm able to fix it by routing my query through 1.1.1.1. e.g.
`dig oracle.com txt @1.1.1.1`

I'm assuming dig is blocked but what is 1.1.1.1 doing to avoid that block?

Comment: well, on the second command you are using a specified DNS server (1.1.1.1) but your initial dig command doesn't show what public server is performing the failing lookup. what DNS server does 192.168.86.1 point to upstream? thats where the issue appears to be.

Comment: @FrankThomas It works for all other DNS queries. I believe my router is proxying 1.1.1.1.

Comment: Please confirm the routers DNS server configuration. Blocking dig specifically isn't really a thing. dig emits DNS traffic just like any other client, and the DNS message format does not have a header field indicating what kind of client originated the message, so if its blocking for dig, its blocking for everything else as well. I'd be more suspicious that you are pointing to an ISP DNS server that is blocking something about the query, like the zone name or the record type (TXT), if the problem is actually being blocked. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#DNS_message_format

Comment: To add to what Frank said, it could also be that the DNS relay/proxy agent at 192.168.86.1 sucks; it might not be the fault of whatever upstream DNS server it's pointing to.

Comment: @FrankThomas It appears to block TXT lookups from consumer ISPs. E.G. [Spectrum](https://digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=oracle.com&type=TXT&useresolver=8.8.4.4&ns=self&nameservers=71.10.216.1%0D%0A71.10.216.2), [Comcast](https://digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=oracle.com&type=TXT&useresolver=8.8.4.4&ns=self&nameservers=75.75.75.75%0D%0A75.75.76.76), and [TimeWarner](https://digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=oracle.com&type=TXT&useresolver=8.8.4.4&ns=self&nameservers=209.18.47.61%0D%0A209.18.47.62)

Comment: gotcha. well, there is your answer, both as to why your queries are blocked, and how cloudflare (1.1.1.1) DNS is able to "bypass" the blocking. yeah I'd guess most residential ISPs do block non-residential-use record queries to their DNS servers just to keep down bandwidth and computational teir usage. I doubt its oracle thats doing the blocking, cause, why??? but perhaps it is at their end.